# Jquery - contains method returning unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The esample is here: http://jsfiddle.net/SsPqS/

I have a div with class="record" I add a click function to every object with class"record". in the click function I have this:(simplified)

```
$(".record").click(function(e) {
                if (!$(e.target).is(':button')) {
                    if ($.contains($(this).parents(".parentDiv"), $("#UserInformation"))) {
                        alert("true");
                    } else {
                        alert("false");
                    }
                }
            });
```

I keep getting the true alert, but i'm not sure why becaue #UserInformation is certinly not in the div with class "parrentDiv"

Am i using the contains function wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks both of you for the very interesting and benificial discussion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$.contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) is intended to take DOM elements, like this:

```
if ($.contains($(this).closest(".parentDiv")[0], $("#UserInformation")[0])) {
```

[You can test the updated demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/btwyu/).

Comment: is there a reason your choosing to use closest rather than parent? Just because it stops once it hits the first div with name parentDiv and it's more efficient?

Comment: @kralco626 - Efficiency, `.closest()` uses alternative methods to crawl to parents (especially in newer browsers).  If you have nested `.parentDiv` elements, use `.parents()`, otherwise I'd stick with `.closest()` :)

Comment: Ya thats what I was thinking. Thanks, i got it to work, however your demo is giving me an error.

Comment: is contains better than the .has method presented below?

Comment: .has because it is acting on the object rather than a static method

Comment: @kralco626 - `.contains()` is much more efficient, yes, it uses some basic DOM methods to get what's contained.

Comment: while we are on the topic, i also sue .children() a lot when there is only going to be one child with that class (just like the parents() example above) is there a better method to use than .children() for this()?

Comment: @kralco626 - nope, `.children()` is appropriate for direct children, it's more selectively applied like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the `has()` method

```
$(".record").click(function(e) { 
    if (!$(e.target).is(':button')) { 
        if ($(this).closest(".parentDiv").has("#UserInformation").length) {             
            alert("true"); 
        } 
        else { 
            alert("false"); 
        }
    } 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

**Description**: Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

Comment: do you belive it to be better than contains?

Comment: `has()` seems much more readable that doing `contains()` on the DOM elements, IMHO

Comment: would this return a JQuery object set or a true or false value? It seems as though it may return a Jquery object set not a true/false value...

Comment: "the .has() method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements."

Comment: or you found use `find()` rather than `has()` unless you want to stay in the context of `.parentDiv`

Comment: while I wish there was an object method for contains because it is more readable, i'm going to stick with contains because it directly returns true/false. Thanks for the insite about .has() though!

Comment: @Nick I did try the Jquery has method: http://api.jquery.com/has/ and it did NOT error. However it always returned true( i'm assuming because the if statment interprests anythign that is not '0' as true) i'll stick with contains though.

Comment: @kralco626 - To explain a bit about `.has()`:  it returns a jQuery object, which is truey, you would do `if($("something").has("something").length)`, but it's still much less efficient, since there's *lots* of expensive DOM crawling going on there :)  Basically, it's intended to be used to reduce the set of elements and use them...not check for existence.